# how to avoid elements in html page move when another element change size

Tags: html, css

I have a list of images. Below is the relevant html code:

```
<ul id="image_list">
<li><a href="h1.jpg"><img alt="" src="t1.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="h2.jpg"><img alt="" src="t2.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="h3.jpg"><img alt="" src="t3.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="h4.jpg"><img alt="" src="t4.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="h5.jpg"><img alt="" src="t5.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="h6.jpg"><img alt="" src="t6.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
```

When one of the images gets the focus or hover a border is displayed, below is the code in css page:

```
li a:focus img {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}       

li a:hover img {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

This code is working but the problem is when on of this images gets the focus or hover, all the elements in the page  move, it is an efect like the whole page is jumping when moving on the list of images. I have tried following code in css, but without success.

```
img {
position: absolute;
}
```

and the following:

```
img {
position: relative;
left: 20px;
}
```

Does any one know how this could be fixed? thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `outline` instead of `border`:

```css
li a:focus img {
  outline: 2px solid blue;
}       

li a:hover img {
  outline: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul id="image_list">
<li><a href="h1.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
<li><a href="h2.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
<li><a href="h3.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
<li><a href="h4.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
<li><a href="h5.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
<li><a href="h6.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow I didn't even know this property existed. And IE8 even supports it! Win!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative margin.

```css
li a:focus img {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin: -2px;
}       

li a:hover img {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin: -2px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="image_list">
<li><a href="h1.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
<li><a href="h2.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
<li><a href="h3.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
<li><a href="h4.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
<li><a href="h5.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
<li><a href="h6.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Reference: [Image Rollover Borders That Do Not Change Layout](http://css-tricks.com/image-rollover-borders-that-do-not-change-layout/)

Comment: Yeah that is a good way too. I guess it depends on how you want the images to look when not focused.

Answer (score 1):

I always add a margin to each element that I remove when displaying the border.

```
li a img {
 margin: 2px;
}

li a:focus img {
margin: 0;
border: 2px solid blue;
}       

li a:hover img {
margin: 0;
border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just always have a 2px border, but it can be transparent when it isnt hovered.

```
li a img {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}

li a:focus img,
li a:hover img {
    border-color: blue;
}
```

I like doing this over manipulating margins because sometimes you might actually want a margin too. I'd rather use margin for what it is supposed to be used for instead of flipping between margin and no margin as well as border and no border. Seems cleaner, in my opinion.

Working example:

```css
li a img {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}       

li a:focus img,
li a:hover img {
  border-color: blue;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="image_list">
<li><a href="h1.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
<li><a href="h2.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
<li><a href="h3.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
<li><a href="h4.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
<li><a href="h5.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
<li><a href="h6.jpg"><img alt="" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4ee102e4ae1b9ab69077f7c471365f69?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a transparent border on default:

```css
li a img {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

li a:focus img {
 border: 2px solid blue;
}       

li a:hover img {
 border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul id="image_list">
<li><a href="h1.jpg"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=1"></a></li>
<li><a href="h2.jpg"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=2"></a></li>
<li><a href="h3.jpg"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=3"></a></li>
<li><a href="h4.jpg"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=4"></a></li>
<li><a href="h5.jpg"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=5"></a></li>
<li><a href="h6.jpg"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/350x150&text=6"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best info I have ever seen on this topic. http://css-tricks.com/image-rollover-borders-that-do-not-change-layout/

A must read resource on this issue.